# downloading ERA5 netCDF daily data for a decade, how to restrict location to reduce data size?

Tags: climate, era

I have download ERA5 netCDF file in order to get precipitation monthly/daily rates for 11 years. But I have realized, there is no option to select my area of interest. It seems it is a big file to handle.

However, I am currently using R language and but still in the basic level.

My question is about if there is anyway to extract precipitation values for a certain area?

Comment: Please edit your title to reflect the actual question. To answer, there is almost certainly a way in R to read just a part of a netCDF file - but I'm not enough of an R user to tell you what it is. Hopefully somebody will come along and aswer.

Comment: @SemidiurnalSimon I've made an edit, how does it look?

Comment: I'd suggest something like "How to read only parts of a netCDF file in R" or similar.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to get this done:

1- you can select the specific domain of interest when downloading the files. This is highly preferred when you have to download a large number of variables and years. ERA5 netCDF are offered in two different formats: either at hourly time steps, or at monthly averages (see [this](https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/cdsapp#!/search?type=dataset&text=era5)). If you need a sub-monthly time steps the global files for many variables for long time periods are extremely heavy in terms of disk space. You could set up a python script to download the data selecting only the domain by following a procedure like the one suggested in this [nice post by Reto Stauffer](https://retostauffer.org/code/Download-ERA5/) (of course there are other ways to do this).

2- you can download the global netCDF of the variable and year under consideration ad use a software to extract your domain of interest.
One of the most efficient systems to do that is using the Climate Data Operator CDO. you could use the `sellonlatbox` with a command like

```
cdo sellonlatbox,LON1,LON2,LAT1,LAT2 Input_file_Name.nc Output_file_Name.nc
```

Or you could use `R`, as for your case, doing something like:

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)

#load your area of interest
setwd("path_domain_shapefile")
domain_shp<-readOGR("shapefile.shp")

#read netCDF
setwd("path_to_ERA5_files_folder")
pr_data<-stack("ERA5_file.nc")

#extract the data for your area of interest
pr_data_domain<-extract(pr_data, domain_shp)

#then you can transform this in a data frame and write it as a csv
```

As reference for basic operations with spatial data in `R`, I would suggest this [introduction guide](http://www.spatialecology.com/beyer/assets/Beyer_Introduction_to_geospatial_analysis_in_R.pdf).

Hope this helps.